# Win Form Design Change as the screen resolution Change

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

We are developing a WinForm application. We have different resolution monitors when designing win form on low resolution and viewing on high resolution, the positions are changed and they appear merged. Could anyone suggest how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance

We are using VS2102 For development. And Framework is 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are starting with development on Windows Desktop you can also explore on WPF, it has a higher initial learning curve than WinForms, but is far more extensible.

If you are still going for WinForms, take a look at dynamically controlling the sizing from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6575311/5788393